# Why are the sets $U_x$ disjoint in this proof of the non path-connectedness of the ordered square, $I_0^2$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $p = 0 \times 0$ and $q = 1 \times 1$. Suppose there is a path $f: [a,b] \to I_o^2$ joining p and q.

By the intermediate value theorem, $f([a,b])$ must contain every point $x \times y$ of $I_o^2$. So, for each $x \in I$, define $U_x = f$$^-$$^1(x \times (0,1))$. The sets $U_x$ are non-empty, open in [a, b] by continuity of $f$, and disjoint.

Choose for each $x \in I$ a rational number $q_x \in U_x$. Thus since $U_x$ are disjoint, the map $x \mapsto q_x$ is an injective mapping of $I$ into $\Bbb Q$.

Another question, how do we know $x \times (0 ,1)$ is open in $I_0^2$?

Answer (score 0):

The set $x\times(0,1)$ being open is by definition of the topology on $I_o^2$.  The pre-images $U_x$ are disjoint because the sets $x\times(0,1)$ are disjoint and the function $f$ is well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

$x \times (0, 1)$ is open in the order topology on $I_0^2$ since it equals an <s>a well-ordered</s> open 'interval' of pairs of points. Open intervals are by definition open. I hope that makes sense.

Let $z \in U_x \cap U_y.$ Then $f(z) \in x \times (0, 1)$ and $f(z) \in y \times (0, 1)$, which is clearly not possible for $x \not=y$.

Comment: $\{x\}\times(0,1)$ is order-isomorphic to $(0,1)$, so it’s certainly not well-ordered. All you need to say is that it’s the open interval $(u,v)$ in the square, where $u=\langle x,0\rangle$ and $v=\langle x,1\rangle$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for the correction. I'd forgotten exactly what it meant for a set to be well-ordered at the time.